# Adding core data to my iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I have been here before, asking for a mapping library that could store objects in a database. Some one told me about the Core Data Framework. I have read a bit about it and I kindda understand it.
I have created some "test Core data projects", where I have worked with simple problems and models ala Person and Group. But now I want to experiment with implementing Core Data to one of my small iPhone apps. How do I do this? Subclassing from NSManagedObject and make a Managed Object Model?
I know that there is more to it, but I havent found anything on google og apples site. Maybe Im looking in wrong direction while googling and searching.
A link to an article/tutorial explaining me how to add Core Data to my project would make my day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a tutorial on iPhone developer site [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). And there are several [sample codes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code) with Core Data as well. These should get you started.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on the Apple's iPhone development site http://developer.apple.com/iphone . It's best to go there to start with them, they are also updated to the latest iPhone SDK. Why not go directly to the best source?

Answer (score 3):

The book, *More iPhone 3 Development* begins with a great tutorial demonstrating how to use Core Data. I've found it incredibly helpful.

Comment: hey rose thanku so much for specify that book.may i get other resources which is useful for iphone development

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic [CoreData screencast](http://archive.org/download/JonathanWolfRentzsch/Introduction_to_Core_Data.mov) that, while not specifically for the iPhone gives a decent introduction to CoreData concepts.