# Best Data Structure for Name and Id(Populating name to table view)

Tags: objective-c

Im programming an app that gets names and id's from a database and I want to make it populate the table view with names and when you click the name it goes to a posts the id of the item clicked. My question is what data structure should i use to store the id and name. Would it be smart to use a Dictionary with a the id as the key and the name as the value?

Database response looks like this

[{"id":1,"name":"Name of Business 1"},{"id":2,"name":"Name of Business 2"}]

Answer (score 0):

For backend - Use `SQLite` or read up on `Core Data`. A dictionary isn't going to persist, isn't the best for large data, and won't allow duplicate keys (names in your case).

[Adding core data to my iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190139/adding-core-data-to-my-iphone-app)

If you're just talking about what to use to hold data you just got from a database, then a dictionary will work fine, but be sure your keys are unique, to prevent collisions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you want to do with the data, there are different approaches

1. Creating a proper class to hold the data

   @interface

   @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *id;

   @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;

   @end
2. Using an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`. Disadvantage is that all the keys are all hardcoded, so heavy manipulation is error-prone.
3. Using `NSDictionary` that maps from `id` to `name`. This is the least flexible one, since it relies on the fact that you have only one field apart from the `id` field. `id` also has to be unique, but I guess that's the case for you.